# Python: script hangs at subprocess.run()

Tags: python, function, subprocess, try-catch, freeze

Whenever I run `subprocess.run({file location})` my whole script hangs until I have closed the windows app that I opened with `subprocess.run({file location})`. The exception doesn't catch it, what should I do?

My code looks like this

```
def open_app(location):
    try:
        subprocess.run(location)
    except subprocess.SubprocessError as error:
        print(error)
```

Comment: What exactly does the file at `location` do?

Comment: It means the .exe file location, so for example `subprocess.run("C:\{path}\Spotify.exe")` will open spotify. @BTables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.run` specifically waits for the process to finish before continuing with the rest of your script. If you want to run it in the background use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)